# Python - Change the original dataframe object from a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to perform a number of operations on a list of dataframes.  I've opted to use a dictionary to help me with this process, but I was wonder if it's possible to reference the originally created dataframe with the changes.

So using the below code as an example, is it possible to call the dfA object with the columns ['a', 'b', 'c'] that were added when it was nested within the dictionary object?

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(data=[1], columns=['x'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame(data=[1], columns=['y'])
dfC = pd.DataFrame(data=[1], columns=['z'])

dfdict = {'A':dfA,
          'B':dfB,
          'C':dfC}

df_dummy = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

for key in dfdict:

    dfdict[str(key)] = pd.concat([dfdict[str(key)], df_dummy], axis=1)
```

Comment: Is this code producing the expected output? What is the expected output?

Comment: You could add columns to the `DataFrames` if you wanted to, but that's usually not encouraged. You're better off creating new `DataFrames`. Why do you want to modify the originals?

Answer (score 0):

The initial `dfA` that you created and the `dfA` `DataFrame` from your dictionary are two different objects. (You can confirm this by running `dfA is dfdict['A']` or `id(dfA) == id(dfdict['A'])`, both of which should return `False`).

To access the *second* (newly created) object you need to call it from the dictionary.

```
dfdict['A']
```

Or:

```
dfdict.get('A')
```

The returned `DataFrame` will have the new columns you added.